# HttpListener BeginGetContext suddenly stopping?

Tags: c#, http

I have a HttpListener which I want to not shut down after each request, so I'm using BeginGetContext to retrieve requests asynchronously. It's just not working properly.

Main starts properly, finding and assigning my IP address for the StartListening() function. However, when I get to `listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequest), listener);` in StartListening() and it jumps to `Response.StartListening(ips);` in Main and then just stops. I'm not sure why. Any hints?

Here's what I have so far.

This is where I start listening for requests:

```
 public static void StartListening(string[] prefixes)
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

        foreach (string s in prefixes)
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://" + s + "/");
        }
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("\nListening...");

        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequest), listener);
    }
```

And here's where I handle the requests:

```
public static void OnRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener) result.AsyncState;
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);


        string url = context.Request.RawUrl;

        string[] split = url.Split('/');

        int lastIndex = split.Length - 1;

        int x, y, z;

        x = Convert.ToInt32(split[lastIndex]);
        y = Convert.ToInt32(split[lastIndex - 1]);
        z = Convert.ToInt32(split[lastIndex - 2]);

        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

        Regex imageRegex = new Regex(@"SomethingSomething");
        var matches = imageRegex.Match(url);

        if (matches.Success)
        {
            string path = @"C:\SomeDir";

            path = String.Format(path, matches.Groups[1].Captures[0],
                                       matches.Groups[2].Captures[0],
                                       matches.Groups[3].Captures[0]);

            // Load the image
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(path);
            MemoryStream bmStream = new MemoryStream();
            bm.Save(bmStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] buffer = bmStream.ToArray();

            // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
            response.ContentLength64 = bmStream.Length;
            response.ContentType = "image/png";
            response.KeepAlive = true;
            Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // You must close the output stream.
            output.Close();
            listener.Stop();
        }

        response.Close();
        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequest), listener);
    }
```

And here's my main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = (args.Length < 1) ? Dns.GetHostName() : args[0];
        try
        {   //Find the IPv4 address 
            IPAddress[] addrs = Array.FindAll(Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList,
                a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            Console.WriteLine("Your IP address is: ");
            foreach (IPAddress addr in addrs)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", name, addr);

            //Automatically set the IP address
            string[] ips = addrs.Select(ip => ip.ToString()).ToArray();
            Response.StartListening(ips);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: <s>Is it a Console Application?</s> Nevermind, you use Console.WriteLine so I assume it is.

Comment: No, but that explains why it stops. I'm writing an answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `BeginGetContext`, it fetches requests asynchronously, so it does not block the calling thread (the Main thread, in this case). And because it doesn't block it, the Main thread ends and thus your program also ends, because it's the Main thread.

You can fix this, by using a `ManualResetEvent` (in the `System.Threading` namespace). This blocks the Main thread.

```
class Program
{
    public static ManualResetEvent ServerManualResetEvent;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // your code to start the server

            ServerManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            ServerManualResetEvent.WaitOne();
        }
        catch
        {
            // your catch code
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Main thread is blocked and your program only stops if you close it, or if you stop it from code:

```
Program.ServerManualResetEvent.Set();
```

Then it does not block the Main thread anymore.

Comment: When I get to ServerManualResetEvent.WaitOne(); I get a {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} exception after putting it exactly where you recommended.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It looks like it's now doing it's job.